# App gets installed on all phones except on a certain brand

Tags: java, android, apk

I am facing a strange problem. My android app gets installed on all android phones viz. Sony, Samsung except that of Micromax. On Micromax phones, I get an error saying : File format not supported. It's just a .apk file. I tried on different Micromax phones but the issue is still there. I am awe-struck. What is wrong ?

Comment: Do these Micromax phones run vanilla Android, or some modified version of the OS?

Comment: @Jim : I am not sure about this. You maybe right. But, does it mean that modded Android versions won't recognize a .apk file ?

Comment: Since Android is open source, and any vendor can make whatever changes they want, there's no way of knowing.  Most phones except the Google Nexus line don't run vanilla Android; they usually run a slightly modded version put out by the vendor.  Perhaps Micromax has a support forum where you can ask?  I don't know, I've never actually heard of Micromax before now.

Comment: Micrommax phones, from what I know, are limited to regional use. If they don't run an old version, it is likely they run a modified one.

Comment: @Jim : Micromax isn't a fairly large brand.

Comment: @zgc7009 : Heights of modification that is, not to recognize a .apk file.

Comment: It is unlikely but you never know. It is more likely that you have a corrupt file or are downloading it from a bad source, but if it is only working on that phone it kind of rules that out.

Comment: @zgc7009 : But, the same file is working on all phones of other brands like Samsung, Sony, LG. I transfer the same file at the same time to a Micromax phone where it doesn't work and to a Non-Micromax phone where it works perfectly.

Comment: Which is why I said it might be a phone restriciton

Comment: @zgc7009 : Yes, maybe. Well, that needs to be figured out.